# How do I make function that needs to do this?

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working in `c++` with `structs` and dynamic allocation,and i need to make function that automatically increases the size of array:

```
structType * array=new structType[max];
```

and i can't use `vectors'. Does anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Create a new array, copy the data, delete the old array. Done. Don't worry, once you get out of school you'll be able to use vectors and other real world tools. Good luck in the meantime. ;)

Comment: There are many examples of how to do this? Have you tried any and not had success?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618526/problems-expanding-an-array-in-c?rq=1   I've tried this,but it didn't work an I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now and I still don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: @lejla didn't work how? Did you replace the pointer parameter with the reference to pointer as described in the answer to the question you linked?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No he can't (he explicitly said he couldn't use `vector`).

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, here's the implementation:

```
void resizeArray(structType*& oldArray, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize) {
    structType* newArray = new structType[newSize];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(oldSize, newSize); ++i)
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    delete[] oldArray;
    oldArray = newArray;
}

structType* array = new structType[max];
resizeArray(array, max, max + 10);
```

Note that the code above is not exception safe: if `newArray[i] = oldArray[i];` throws then you will leak memory. But I believe this is enough to get you started.