# C++: function to expand an array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

Before asking this question, I looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618526/problems-expanding-an-array-in-c) and tried to use its code to solve my problem, but it did not work.

I'm trying to write a function that expands a given static array of objects. Here's the function as it currently stands, based on code from the above-linked question:

```
void MyClass::expand_array(MyClass *&old_array, int &old_array_size,
    int new_slots)
{
    MyClass *transfer_array = new MyClass[old_array_size + new_slots];

    for (int i = 0; i < old_array_size; i++) {
        transfer_array[i] = old_array[i];
    }

    delete[] old_array;
    old_array = transfer_array;
    transfer_array = NULL;
}
```

This does not even compile. Here's the compiler's output:

```
program.cpp:110:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::expand_array(MyClass [10], int&, int)’
program.cpp:110:54: note: candidate is:
program.cpp:41:6: note: static void MyClass::expand_array(MyClass*&, int&, int)
program.cpp:41:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass [10]’ to ‘MyClass*&’
program.cpp:122:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::expand_array(MyClass [10], int&, int)’
program.cpp:122:54: note: candidate is:
program.cpp:41:6: note: static void MyClass::expand_array(MyClass*&, int&, int)
program.cpp:41:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyClass [10]’ to ‘MyClass*&’
program.cpp:143:11: warning: deleting array ‘MyClass tmp_cards [10]’ [enabled by default]
```

(The last line of the output comes from trying to delete the last iteration of the array.)

Comment: The error has to do with what you are calling the function with. The first argument takes a reference to a pointer but you are supplying an array.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider returning the new array. This is (better) self-documenting. (Were it my code, I wouldn't modify the old_array pointer at all. But, to each their own.)

Comment: @0x499602D2 What, then, is the proper way to pass an array to a function?

Comment: @jpaugh The original array needs to maintain the same name through several of these operations and I don't think that's possible with returning. Also, I didn't know you could return an array in C++.

Comment: Can't you return pointers to anything? But I digress.. `C++` is not my strong suite; good luck.

Comment: "...expands a given static array of objects" You can stop right there. Fixed arrays are not dynamically resizable. Their magnitude is decided at compile-time; not run-time. Were this a *dynamically* allocated sequence what you want would be easily doable.

Comment: Just use `MyClass (&old_array)[10]` as the argument.

Comment: Re your edit: Attach a debugger and step thru. Clearly either `tmp_cards` is not a valid pointer, or `index` is larger than the storage to which `tmp_cards` points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be running afoul of array-pointer equivalence. By `array` in this context I am referring to a C-array, e.g.

```
MyClass a[10];
```

In C, and so C++, arrays can decay to pointers.

```
void f(int input[]);
```

The language provides no mechanism for this function to tell how many its it was receiving, so for the purpose of a function call, the above array decays to a pointer. That is, within the body of the above function, `input` is of type `int*`.

This also occurs in other places to allow us to do pointer-math no arrays and pointer-like operations on arrays:

```
char a[10];
sizeof(a); // understands a is really an array and evaluates to 10
sizeof(*a); // decays a to a pointer and returns sizeof(char)
char* b = a + 1; // equivalent to b = &a[1];
b[1] = 0; // equivalent to *(b + 1) = 0;
```

However, you are trying to take a reference to a pointer. In this context, arrays do *not* decay, consider:

```
void f(int*& ptr)
{
    ptr = nullptr;
}

void x()
{
    int a[16];
    f(a);
}
```

`a` is not a pointer to 16 ints, it *is* 16 ints, on the stack. We fundamentally cannot relocate `a`.

If you require a resizable array, you will need to use allocation:

```
MyClass* array = new MyClass[10];
MyClass::expand_array(array, 10, 20);
delete [] array;
```

This said, I want to point out that this approach is terrible because it exposes the pointers to the consumer. Instead, you should move the tracking of size and where the array is currently stored *into* your MyClass class. Perhaps take a look at [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

But in general, something more like this: http://ideone.com/4hgri4

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

// CAVEAT EMPTOR: This is a partial, naive implementation,
// it lacks copy/move constructor, operator=, iterators and
// many other things. It is solely intended to demonstrate
// internalizing the paired-state components of size and data
// to provide a discrete encapsulation of the concept of a
// dynamically sized array-like allocation.

class MyArray
{
    // create an alias for the type we're using,
    // this will come in handy when you learn templates.
    typedef int value_type;

    value_type* m_data;
    size_t m_size;

public:
    MyArray() : m_data(nullptr), m_size(0) {}
    MyArray(size_t defaultSize) : m_data(nullptr), m_size(0)
    {
        resize(defaultSize);
    }

    void resize(size_t newSize)
    {
        if (newSize > size()) {
            value_type* newData = new value_type[newSize];
            if (m_data) {
                std::copy(m_data, m_data + size(), newData);
                delete [] m_data;
            }
            m_data = newData;
        }
        m_size = newSize;
        if (m_size == 0 && m_data) {
            delete [] m_data;
            m_data = nullptr;
        }
    } 

    value_type operator[](size_t index) const { return m_data[index]; }
    value_type& operator[](size_t index) { return m_data[index]; }

    size_t size() const { return m_size; }

    void push_back(value_type newValue)
    {
        resize(m_size + 1);
        m_data[size() - 1] = newValue;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyArray a;
    a.resize(4);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    a.push_back(10);

    std::cout << "Values:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << a[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For more on array-pointer-equivalence, see the [C++ FAQ section on it](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html).

Comment: I am already using this exact approach elsewhere in the code: `MyClass* array = new MyClass[10]; MyClass::expand_array(array, 10, 20); delete [] array;`. But it is not working.

Comment: @EMBLEM What do you mean by "it is not working"? You need to elaborate so we can help you.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The code does not compile with the error messages shown in the question.

Comment: @kfson Wouldn't the array decay into a pointer but binding it to a reference would fail because the pointer is a temporary (rvalue) and a reference only accepts lvalues?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Please disregard my previous statement and give me a moment to compile. I was using a static array and not a pointer to one, the cause of my problems.

Comment: @EMBLEM The compiler error you posted states, explicitly `no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::expand_array(MyClass [10], int&, int)` and that would only happen if you were calling it with an array value and not a pointer. It said this was on line 110. I would suggest you look at line 110 :) Also, I've added an example array class to the answer.

Comment: When you write `MyClass* array = new MyClass[10];` the type of `array` is `MyClass*`. The *compiler* does not remember the `[10]`, only uses it to construct the call to `new`, because it is possible to overload `new` and do things like implement allocations from pools, etc.

Comment: Actually, I think it's because of *overload resolution* that the array doesn't decay. The OP must be implementing more than one overload for `expand_array`. The implicit decay to a pointer doesn't happen before overload resolution succeeds hence the error message that shows `MyClass::expand_array(MyClass[10], int&, int)` instead of `MyClass::expand_array(MyClass*, int&, int)`.

Comment: No, you simply can't pass an array to a parameter that takes a reference-to-pointer: http://ideone.com/hIEqJK

Comment: @kfsone I'm still in need of a little more aid; please see my edit to the question.

Comment: @EMBLEM You can't extend the discussion with a new problem. You have to make a new question for that.

Comment: You *can't* expand a static array. That's part of the definition of "static". It's fixed. The only thing you can do is create a static object which *encapsulates* dynamic storage - as std::vector does or the MyArray demonstrates above. A *static* object, in a function scope, is on the stack, if you expand it, you'll break things (although you could use 'alloca' to allocate memory below the current stack frame, but this is ill-advised). If it is in the global scope, then it is in the program's data section which can't be resized.

Comment: @EMBLEM For clarification, an array allocated with `new` is *not* static.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to expand array is defined as myclass *&, looking at the code I think you need to make it myclass * * and adjust the calling code. I'm guessing you are declaring myclass a[10] and are trying to pass that, which is never going to work - you have to pass an array that you allocated with new if you are going to delete it.

Comment: If it were a `MyClass*` he wouldn't be able to assign an array to it.

Comment: I've tried it like that and it still doesn't compile.